# Why the speed of a Java process inside multiple loops slows down as it goes?

Tags: java, performance, loops

I'm using Win 7, Java 8, on a multicore Intel workstation.
I have something like this :

```
  int SampleWeeksArray[]=new int[]{23,25,33},IdArray[]=new int[]{0,1,2};

  for (int StartDay=25;StartDay<36;StartDay++)
    for (int SampleWeeks : SampleWeeksArray)
      for (int Id : IdArray)
        for (float ValueFactor=0.08f;ValueFactor<0.13f;ValueFactor+=0.01)
        {
          DataDigester dataDigester=new DataDigester();
          dataDigester.StartDay=StartDay;
          dataDigester.SampleWeeks=SampleWeeks;
          dataDigester.Id=Id;
          dataDigester.ValueFactor=ValueFactor;
          dataDigester.DoRun();
        }
```

Inside dataDigester.DoRun() it reads in some text data files, parse each line and do some statistics with arrays, vectors and hashmaps and it uses ThreadPoolExecutor to run multiple processes, then save the results to a file.

The strange thing is each single run of DoRun() takes only 10 minutes, but inside the loops, it started with 10 min. but gradually slows down to 20, 30 min. for each DoRun().

If I stop the loop when it's taking 30 min., then start over from where I stopped, it again took 10 min. and eventually slows down to 20, 30 min. again. Why ?

I even put in the following lines after DoRun(), but it didn't improve speed, still slows down :

```
   Thread.sleep(20*1000);                     // Rest for 20 seconds
   System.gc();
```

Inside each loop, DataDigester dataDigester=new DataDigester() creates a new object, it should be recycled after the DoRun(), why it slowed down ?

I've also noticed from Windows Task Manager, the memory usage goes up as the loops keep going. It seems Java somehow burdens itself with something and slows down, so in this case how to keep the speed at a constant of 10 min. for each run within the loops ?

Comment: Might there be more data as time goes on?

Comment: Don't use double or float for iterators.  This is because floating types are imprecise and you can get an unexpected result. Also try to use Java code conventions where variables start with lower case. e.g. `for (int v = 8; v <= 13; v++) float valueFactor = v / 100.0f;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing what DataDigester is and does, but I can think of a number
of possible reasons:

1. if DataDigester.DoRun starts up a new thread - then as the number of threads goes up,
   the time available per thread goes down. If it utilizes the hardware threads, then the
   time will go significantly up once you go from 1 to 2 threads per hardware thread.
2. DataDigester may have a static structure that it adds to, and which grows slower and
   slower the more you add into it

Comment: That's what I suspected, I'll look into them, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Declare just one `DataDigester` and reuse that for all of your loops instead of creating thousands and thousands of them.

```
int SampleWeeksArray[]=new int[]{23,25,33},IdArray[]=new int[]{0,1,2};

DataDigester dataDigester;
for (int StartDay=25;StartDay<36;StartDay++)
    for (int SampleWeeks : SampleWeeksArray)
        for (int Id : IdArray)
            for (float ValueFactor=0.08f;ValueFactor<0.13f;ValueFactor+=0.01)
            {
                dataDigester=new DataDigester();
                dataDigester.StartDay=StartDay;
                dataDigester.SampleWeeks=SampleWeeks;
                dataDigester.Id=Id;
                dataDigester.ValueFactor=ValueFactor;
                dataDigester.DoRun();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should help with your Garbage Collection issues and the timing too.

Comment: It was like what you suggested at beginning, but I noticed the slow down, so I moved the DataDigester dataDigester; inside the loops, I suppose it should be recycled after each loop, and therefore a constant speed. But that's not the case.

Comment: Them you should be looking at what happens inside DataDigester for performance increases. And if DD.DoRun() kicks off a Thread perhaps at limiting the ThreadPool, you could be swapping Threads too often and racking up the CPU overhead that comes with it pretty quickly.